# Problems converting a large file to a panel using read_csv into python pandas

Tags: python, large-files, pandas

I have been trying to load in a large-ish file `(~480MB, 5,250,000 records, stock price daily data -dt, o, h, l, c, v, val , adj, fv, sym, code - for about 4,500 instruments)` into pandas using `read_csv`. It runs fine, and creates the DataFrame. However, on conversion to a Panel, the values for several stocks are way off, and nowhere close to the values in the original csv file.

I then attempted to use the *chunksize* parameter in `read_csv`, and used a for loop to:

```
reader = read_csv("bigfile.csv",index_col=[0,9],parse_dates=True,names=['n1','n2',...,'nn'], chunksize=100000)

new_df = DataFrame(reader.get_chunk(1))

for chunk in reader:
    new_df = concat(new_df, chunk)
```

This reads in the data, but:

1. I get the same erroneous values (edit:) when converting to a Panel
2. It takes ages longer than the plain `read_csv` (no iterator)

Any ideas how to get around this?

Edit:
Changed the question to reflect the problem - the dataframe is fine, conversion to a Panel is the problem. Found the error appearing even after splitting the input csv file, merging and then converting to a panel. If i maintain a multi-index DataFrame, there is no problem and the values are represented correctly.

Comment: It is likely that the problem is with your CSV file.  It may contain delimiter characters in unexpected places, causing the CSV parsing to go awry.  Try to narrow down the problem by creating a test file that is initially a copy of your data, then gradually remove parts of the file until you zero in on the part of the file that causes the problem.

Comment: Can you share the file with me so I can debug? I created an issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1855 . If it's not public data can you e-mail me directly wesmckinn at gmail dot com

Answer (score 1):

Some bugs have been fixed in the DataFrame to Panel code. Please try with the latest pandas version (preferably upcoming 0.10) and let us know if you're still having issues.

Comment: Will do Wes. Thanks. Think i'm on 0.8.1 - upgrading to 0.10 right now

Answer (score 0):

If you know a few specific values that are off, you might just examine those lines specifically in your csv file.  You should also check out the [docs on `csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), particularly in terms of [dialects](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) and the [Sniffer class](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer). You might be able to find some setting that will correctly detect how the the file is delimited.

If you find that the errors go away when you look only at specific lines, that probably means that there is an erroneous/missing line break somewhere that is throwing things off.

Finally, if you can't seem to find patterns of correct/incorrect lines, you might try (randomly or otherwise) selecting a subset of the lines in your csv file and see whether the error is occurring because of the size of the file (I'd guess this would be unlikely, but I'm not sure).

Comment: I did just that - based on @BrenBarn's suggestion, I split the big file into two - not in half, but from the offending line onwards. I end up with two dataframes - df1 and df2. I then used `df1.join(df2)` to give me one large DataFrame. On it's own, the DataFrame is fine - the problem with erroneous values arises only when i convert the DataFrame to a Panel using `to_panel()`. I retried the 'big' file and kept it as a DataFrame - no problems. Conversion to Panel seems to be the offender - wonder if this is a bug.